# Distributed FS for storing data in the single "master" node and duplicating that data, which is used on "worker" nodes

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization, distributed, hadoop

I am looking for a DFS for unified data access and caching used files within a small cluster.
We are currently using NFS to RAID node, and it seems not the best way to further scaling. So, I am looking for DFS with such work logic:
All data is stored on the master node, and workers store only recently used data, i.e.:

1. Worker connects to the cluster,
2. It access some path like "dfs://test/test.png",
3. File is downloaded to worker from master node,
4. Next access will be to the local copy of the "test.png".

If a worker adds new files to DFS, it first creates the local copy and then loads it to the master node in background mode.

If a worker has no additional space for new files, it overwrites firstly accessed files.
Most of the data is unstructured read-only files(pictures or videos as parts of datasets)

Which technology is most appropriate for such use case? Is it possible, using popular solutions, such as hadoop or alluxio?